# How to get the count of output in python

Tags: python, count

I am trying to count the output in python. 'len' seems to be not working with the output. Following is my code

```
for i in range (0, 5):
    print i
```

The output is

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

I want to print the count of 'i' which should give me count of '5'

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do but my two ways would be

One way is to use `len`

```
i =len(range (0, 5))
print i
```

Other way is using for:

```
j=0
for i in range (0, 5):
    #Other things you want to do
    j+=1
print j
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I am looking for. :)

Comment: @Srivamsi happy to help

Answer (score 3):

Use `enumerate` to count the iterations:

```
count = 0
for count, i in enumerate(range(5),1):
    print(i)
print(count)
```

If you want the size of a list use len:

```
print(len(range(5)))
```

Comment: If you do `count = 0` before the loop, it even works with an empty loop, such as `range(0, 0)`.